# file upload using jquery ajax

Tags: c#, json, jquery, generic-handler

I want to upload a image with a description like:

```
data = '{"filename":"' + myfilename + '", "file":"' + file + '", "description":"' +
    description + '"}';

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "filehandler.ashx",
    data: data,
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("There was error uploading file!");
    }
});
```

how can I do it? I can't read file as `HttpPostedFile` in generic handler.
`context.Request.Form` also doesn't have any keys.

Comment: Please add the problematic code

Comment: @AmiramKorach I don't know how to write handler to get file and description separately.

Comment: With this code, I do not see how you could upload anything. Here is a post of a js object containing strings. Uploading a file cannot be achieved this way unfortunately. Basically it's the browser's job to set the file name (for security reasons). now maybe I did not got your snippet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sorry, If I not posted fully what I did in question. Anyway I got it to work.

```
var data = new FormData();

data.append("name", filename);
data.append("file", file);
```

In generic handler

```
HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files["file"];
string fileName = context.Request.Form["filename"];
```

[Using FormData Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

Comment: Only work in recent browsers tho, but since IE10 now also works on Win7 it's usable :)

Answer (score 2):

you cant post files with ajax you have to post it in a iframe to have the same result

this is what I did

```
var form = "#myform";
var url = "http://post.it/";
var iframeName = 'iframePost' + (new Date()).getTime(); 
$('<iframe id="'+iframeName+'" name="' + iframeName + '" style="display:none;"/>').appendTo('body');
$(form).attr('target',iframeName)
    .attr('action',url)
    .attr('enctype','multipart/form-data')
    .append('<input type="hidden" name="_iframe" value="' + iframeName + '" />');
    form.submit();
```

to have a callback let the iframe return a script with something like

```
window.parent.callBack(data);
```